# How create two table Category and Product with relationship

Tags: sql, sqlite

I want to create two tables `Category` and `Product` in `SQLITE`. Does anyone know how I can do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this...

**Category Table**

```
    CREATE TABLE Category (
     id integer PRIMARY KEY,
     category_name text NOT NULL
   );
```

**Product Table**

```
  CREATE TABLE Product (
     p_id integer PRIMARY KEY,
     p_name text NOT NULL,
     category_id integer NOT NULL,
     FOREIGN KEY (category_id) REFERENCES Category(id)
    );
```